# AJAX to JQuery Conversion Assistance

Tags: jquery, html, ajax, forms

Would anyone be willing to help me out on this script?

I just need someone to take this snippet of AJAX and basically reprogram it with jQuery so I can study it and learn more about how to use jQuery.  This is a current working bit of AJAX that I am using and I think if I could see it in jQuery, it would jump start my learning process...

So, if anyone would be so kind, this is the script:

```
function CreateXmlHttpObject() { //function to return the xml http object
    var xmlhttp = false;
    try {
        xmlhttp = new XMLHttpRequest(); //creates a new ajax object
    } catch(e) {
        try {
            xmlhttp = new ActiveXObject("Microsoft.XMLHTTP"); //this is for IE browser
        } catch(e) {
            try {
                req = new ActiveXObject("Msxml2.XMLHTTP"); //this is for IE browser
            } catch(e1) {
                xmlhttp = false; //error creating object
            }
        }
    }
    return xmlhttp;
}

function getMetaID(strURL) {
    var req = CreateXmlHttpObject(); // function to get xmlhttp object
    if(req) {
        req.onreadystatechange = function () {
            if(req.readyState == 4) { //data is retrieved from server
                if(req.status == 200) { // which reprents ok status                    
                    document.getElementById('meta_id').innerHTML = req.responseText; //put the results of the requests in or element
                } else {
                    alert("There was a problem while using XMLHTTP:\n");
                }
            }
        }
        req.open("GET", strURL, true); //open url using get method
        req.send(null); //send the results
    }
}
```

And this is on the page that call the functions (PHP):

```
echo '<select name="meta_id" onChange="getMetaID('."'".'http://www.mysite.com/backoffice/meta_tags/ajaxpageid.php?meta_id='."'".'+this.value)">';
```

It's a `<div>` after that.

Hopefully this is enough information to get it to make sense.  I certainly appreciate any help...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
   <script src="http://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.9.1.js"></script>
  <script src="http://code.jquery.com/ui/1.10.2/jquery-ui.js"></script>
```

add these files before using jQuery

```
$.ajax(serverUrl, {
   type: "POST",
   data:{ strURL:strUR},
   statusCode: {
      200: function (response) {           
      },
      201: function (response) {           
      },
      400: function (response) {
       },
      404: function (response) {
       );
      }
   }, success: function () {

   },
});
```